# epoll-based server fails (mutual authentication)

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, openssl

Based on the examples at http://simplestcodings.blogspot.com/2010/08/secure-server-client-using-openssl-in-c.html I have written the following epoll server code to replace the regular tcp sockets with SSL. My code is slightly modified to do mutual authentication and verify the certs since I add

`SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,"/home/test/ssl/cert_files/cacert.pem",NULL);`.

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

I have also generated server cert, client cert, server key, client key, and of course cacert.pem files from the IBM tutorial http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fliaat%2Fliaatseccreatecskeycert.htm

I ran the single server - single client code and it runs perfectly fine. Inspired by this I wanted to see how the epoll server code would behave but then I ran into issues. Here is the code for the server

**Code that does not work**

```
//(c) 2014 enthusiasticgeek for stackoverflow - epollserver.cc
//============================================================================

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

#define FAIL    -1

#define MAXEVENTS 64


SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void)
{   const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* load all error messages */
    method = SSLv23_server_method();  /* create new server-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* create new context from method */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{

    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);
    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,"/home/test/ssl/cert_files/cacert.pem",NULL);

    /* set the local certificate from CertFile */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
    }
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
    }
    /* verify private key */
    if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) )
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
    abort();
    }
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{   X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* Get certificates (if available) */
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
    printf("Server certificates:\n");
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
    free(line);
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
    free(line);
    X509_free(cert);
    }
    else
    printf("No certificates.\n");
}

static int
AibSocketNonBlocking (int sfd)
{
    int flags, s;

    flags = fcntl (sfd, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags == -1)
    {
    perror ("fcntl");
    return -1;
    }

    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    s = fcntl (sfd, F_SETFL, flags);
    if (s == -1)
    {
    perror ("fcntl");
    return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int
AibCreateAndBind (char *port)
{
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
    int s, sfd;

    memset (&hints, 0, sizeof (struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;     /* Return IPv4 and IPv6 choices */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; /* We want a TCP socket */
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     /* All interfaces */

    s = getaddrinfo (NULL, port, &hints, &result);
    if (s != 0)
    {
    fprintf (stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror (s));
    return -1;
    }

    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next)
    {
    sfd = socket (rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
    if (sfd == -1)
        continue;

    s = bind (sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen);
    if (s == 0)
    {
        /* We managed to bind successfully! */
        break;
    }

    close (sfd);
    }

    if (rp == NULL)
    {
    fprintf (stderr, "Could not bind\n");
    return -1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo (result);

    return sfd;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL_library_init();
    ctx = InitServerCTX();        /* initialize SSL */
    LoadCertificates(ctx, "/home/test/ssl/cert_files/servercert.pem", "/home/test/ssl/cert_files/serverkey.pem"); /* load certs */

    int sfd, s;
    int efd;
    struct epoll_event aibevent;
    struct epoll_event *aibevents;
    if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s [port]\n", argv[0]);
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char portt[sizeof (unsigned int)];
    snprintf(portt,sizeof portt + 1,"%u",atoi(argv[1]));

    printf("sizeof %s argv[1] = %d\n",argv[1], sizeof(argv[1]));
    printf("sizeof %s portt = %d\n",portt, sizeof(portt));

    sfd = AibCreateAndBind (portt);//argv[1]);
    if (sfd == -1) {
    abort ();
    }
    s = AibSocketNonBlocking (sfd);
    if (s == -1) {
    abort ();
    }
    s = listen (sfd, SOMAXCONN);
    if (s == -1) {
    perror ("listen");
    abort ();
    }
    efd = epoll_create1 (0);
    if (efd == -1) {
    perror ("epoll_create");
    abort ();
    }
    aibevent.data.fd = sfd;
    aibevent.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
    s = epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sfd, &aibevent);
    if (s == -1) {
    perror ("epoll_ctl");
    abort ();
    }

    // Buffer where events are returned
    //events = static_cast<epoll_event*>(calloc (MAXEVENTS, sizeof event));
    //aibevents = static_cast<epoll_event*>(malloc (MAXEVENTS * sizeof aibevent));
    aibevents = new epoll_event[MAXEVENTS * sizeof aibevent];

    // The event loop
    while (true)
    {
    int n, i;

    n = epoll_wait (efd, aibevents, MAXEVENTS, -1);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((aibevents[i].events & EPOLLERR) ||
                (aibevents[i].events & EPOLLHUP) ||
                (!(aibevents[i].events & EPOLLIN)))
        {
            // An error has occured on this fd, or the socket is not
            // ready for reading (why were we notified then?)
            fprintf (stderr, "epoll error\n");
            close (aibevents[i].data.fd);
            continue;
        } else if (sfd == aibevents[i].data.fd) {
            // We have a notification on the listening socket, which
            // means one or more incoming connections.
            while (1)
            {

                struct sockaddr in_addr;
                socklen_t in_len;
                int infd;
                char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST], sbuf[NI_MAXSERV];

                in_len = sizeof in_addr;
                infd = accept (sfd, &in_addr, &in_len);
                if (infd == -1)
                {
                    if ((errno == EAGAIN) ||(errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
                        // We have processed all incoming
                        // connections.
                        break;
                    } else {
                        perror ("accept");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                s = getnameinfo (&in_addr, in_len,
                                 hbuf, sizeof hbuf,
                                 sbuf, sizeof sbuf,
                                 NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
                if (s == 0) {
                    printf("Accepted connection on descriptor %d "
                           "(host=%s, port=%s)\n", infd, hbuf, sbuf);
                }

                // Make the incoming socket non-blocking and add it to the
                // list of fds to monitor.
                s = AibSocketNonBlocking (infd);
                if (s == -1) {
                    abort ();
                }
                aibevent.data.fd = infd;
                aibevent.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
                s = epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, infd, &aibevent);
                if (s == -1) {
                    perror ("epoll_ctl");
                    abort ();
                }



            }
            continue;
        } else {
            // We have data on the fd waiting to be read. Read and
            // display it. We must read whatever data is available
            // completely, as we are running in edge-triggered mode
            // and won't get a notification again for the same
            // data.
            int done = 0;
            int sd;

            SSL *ssl;

            while (1)
            {
                ssize_t count;
                char buf[1024];
                char reply[1024];

                printf("Performing exchange.\n");

                ssl = SSL_new(ctx);              /* get new SSL state with context */
                SSL_set_fd(ssl, aibevents[i].data.fd);      /* set connection socket to SSL state */

                printf("Performing exchange 1.\n");

                const char* HTMLecho="<html><body><pre>%s</pre></body></html>\n\n";

                if ( SSL_accept(ssl) == FAIL ) {    /* do SSL-protocol accept */
                    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
                    printf("Performing exchange Error 1.\n");
                    done = 1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    ShowCerts(ssl);        /* get any certificates */
                    count = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get request */
                    if ( count > 0 )
                    {
                        buf[count] = 0;
                        printf("Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf);
                        sprintf(reply, HTMLecho, buf);   /* construct reply */
                        SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply)); /* send reply */
                    } else {
                        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
                        printf("Performing exchange Error 2.\n");
                        done = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);       /* get socket connection */
                /*
                                    count = read (aibevents[i].data.fd, buf, sizeof buf);
                                    if (count == -1)
                                    {
                                        // If errno == EAGAIN, that means we have read all
                                        // data. So go back to the main loop.
                                        if (errno != EAGAIN)
                                        {
                                            perror ("read");
                                            done = 1;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else if (count == 0)
                                    {
                                        // End of file. The remote has closed the
                                        // connection.
                                        done = 1;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    // Write the buffer to standard output
                                    s = write (1, buf, count);
                                    if (s == -1)
                                    {
                                        perror ("write");
                                        abort ();
                                    }
                                    printf(" read correctly (n > 0) n==%d\n",s);
                                    printf("msg: %s\n", buf);
                                    write(aibevents[i].data.fd, buf,s);
                                    memset(buf,'\0', s);
                */
            }
            if (done)
            {
                printf("Freeing data.\n");
                SSL_free(ssl);         /* release SSL state */
                close(sd);          /* close connection */

                //printf ("Closed connection on descriptor %d\n",
                //        aibevents[i].data.fd);
                // Closing the descriptor will make epoll remove it
                // from the set of descriptors which are monitored.
                //close (aibevents[i].data.fd);
            }
        }
    }
    }
    //free (aibevents);
    delete[] aibevents;
    close (sfd);


    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);         /* release context */

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The single server- single client code are listed below for reference. Note that I am using the same client code to interact with the epoll server.

Single server code. **Works**

```
//SSL-Single Server code that works ! used as a reference for epoll server
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

#define FAIL    -1

int OpenListener(int port)
{   int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if ( bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
    {
    perror("can't bind port");
    abort();
    }
    if ( listen(sd, 10) != 0 )
    {
    perror("Can't configure listening port");
    abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void)
{   const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* load all error messages */
    method = SSLv23_server_method();  /* create new server-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* create new context from method */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{

    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);
    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,"/home/test/ssl/cert_files/cacert.pem",NULL);

    /* set the local certificate from CertFile */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
    }
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
    }
    /* verify private key */
    if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) )
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
    abort();
    }
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{   X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* Get certificates (if available) */
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
    printf("Server certificates:\n");
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
    free(line);
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
    free(line);
    X509_free(cert);
    }
    else
    printf("No certificates.\n");
}

void Servlet(SSL* ssl) /* Serve the connection -- threadable */
{   char buf[1024];
    char reply[1024];
    int sd, bytes;
    const char* HTMLecho="<html><body><pre>%s</pre></body></html>\n\n";

    if ( SSL_accept(ssl) == FAIL )     /* do SSL-protocol accept */
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else
    {
    ShowCerts(ssl);        /* get any certificates */
    bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get request */
    if ( bytes > 0 )
    {
        buf[bytes] = 0;
        printf("Client msg: \"%s\"\n", buf);
        sprintf(reply, HTMLecho, buf);   /* construct reply */
        SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply)); /* send reply */
    }
    else
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);       /* get socket connection */
    SSL_free(ssl);         /* release SSL state */
    close(sd);          /* close connection */
}

int main(int count, char *strings[])
{   SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    char *portnum;

    if ( count != 2 )
    {
    printf("Usage: %s <portnum>\n", strings[0]);
    exit(0);
    }
    SSL_library_init();
    portnum = strings[1];
    ctx = InitServerCTX();        /* initialize SSL */
    LoadCertificates(ctx, "/home/test/ssl/cert_files/servercert.pem", "/home/test/ssl/cert_files/serverkey.pem"); /* load certs */
    server = OpenListener(atoi(portnum));    /* create server socket */
    while (1)
    {   struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
    SSL *ssl;

    int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);  /* accept connection as usual */
    printf("Connection: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);              /* get new SSL state with context */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);      /* set connection socket to SSL state */
    Servlet(ssl);         /* service connection */
    }
    close(server);          /* close server socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);         /* release context */
}
```

Single client code **Works**

```
// Single Client Code that works!
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define FAIL    -1


//Added the LoadCertificates how in the server-side makes.
void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{

    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);
    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,"/home/test/ssl/cert_files/cacert.pem",NULL);
    /* set the local certificate from CertFile */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
    }
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
    }
    /* verify private key */
    if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) )
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
    abort();
    }
}

int OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port)
{   int sd;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL )
    {
    perror(hostname);
    abort();
    }
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
    if ( connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
    {
    close(sd);
    perror(hostname);
    abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{   const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(); /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
    SSL_load_error_strings(); /* Bring in and register error messages */
    method = SSLv23_client_method(); /* Create new client-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method); /* Create new context */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{   X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
    printf("Server certificates:\n");
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
    free(line); /* free the malloc'ed string */
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
    free(line); /* free the malloc'ed string */
    X509_free(cert); /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
    }
    else
    printf("No certificates.\n");
}

int main(int count, char *strings[])
{
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    SSL *ssl;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes;
    if ( count != 3 )
    {
    printf("Usage: %s <host/ip> <portnum>\n", strings[0]);
    exit(0);
    }

    char* hostname=strings[1];//"127.0.0.1";
    char* portnum=strings[2];//"3334";
    char CertFile[] = "/home/test/ssl/cert_files/clientcert.pem";
    char KeyFile[] = "/home/test/ssl/cert_files/clientkey.pem";

    SSL_library_init();

    ctx = InitCTX();
    LoadCertificates(ctx, CertFile, KeyFile);
    server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum));
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx); /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server); /* attach the socket descriptor */
    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL ) /* perform the connection */
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else
    {   char *msg = "Hello???";

    printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
    ShowCerts(ssl); /* get any certs */
    SSL_write(ssl, msg, strlen(msg)); /* encrypt & send message */
    bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get reply & decrypt */
    buf[bytes] = 0;
    printf("Received: \"%s\"\n", buf);
    SSL_free(ssl); /* release connection state */
    }
    close(server); /* close socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx); /* release context */
    return 0;
}
```

I did compilation using 
        `g++ -g <src>.cc -o <src> -lssl -lcrypto` for each of the three files (I had a Makefile)

The error that see is

`./tcpserver_epoll 3334
sizeof 3334 argv[1] = 4
sizeof 3334 portt = 4
Accepted connection on descriptor 5 (host=127.0.0.1, port=44716)
Performing exchange.
Performing exchange 1.
Performing exchange Error 1.
Freeing data.
Performing exchange.
Performing exchange 1.
3072792824:error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_srvr.c:628:
Performing exchange Error 1.
Freeing data.`

I am wondering if I have to create multiple instances of `SSL_CTX *ctx;`. I am a bit lost. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:** Thanks to everyone for guidance. I found an example here that closely matches what I want 
http://bendecplusplus.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ssl_mycode/epoll_ssl/server.c
http://bendecplusplus.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ssl_mycode/epoll_ssl/client.c

Comment: I can't see any threads in your examples. Is it really about multi-threading or about asynchronous I/O?

Comment: well you are correct indeed. My bad. I had two versions - one threaded and one with epoll. I pasted one with epoll. I have updated my question slightly to match the content I want answered. Thanks.

Comment: **TLDR** comes to mind. Can you get this reduced to something more manageable? And I'm not sure how I feel about the copyright. Is it worth my time (and that of the community) since you seem to want to keep everything to yourself. Since you seem to want to keep everything to yourself, maybe a paid consultant would better serve your needs.

Comment: First of all I have listed all code, nothing is hidden, so I do not know what you are talking about. Secondly, TLDR and keeping everything to yourself (which is basically not listing) is kind of contradictory. Thirdly, I visited your profile and respect you for your knowledge of SSL, cryptography but I advise stop making assumptions about people. I would appreciate more if you want me to list something that I should, I would. I do not gain anything by hiding and /or Copyright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is very hard to read (how about proper indentation?) but I think the main problem is, that you consider a return of -1 from `SSL_accept` to be a fatal error.

According to the man page (which is true in this case) -1 can happen on fatal error or "It can also occur of action is need to continue the operation for non-blocking BIOs. Call SSL_get_error() with the return value ret to find out the reason.". So you have to check the error and if its `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` you have to wait the socket is readable and on `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` until its writable.

Comment: +1 good point.  I got caught out years ago by this on windows, with the error code of `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` which one specifically checks for and ignores (in my case).

Comment: +1 Thank you. I can now explore more in this direction. I will post updated answer as soon as I can this code working.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if I have to create multiple instances of SSL_CTX *ctx;

No, you can use a single `SSL_CTX*`.

The `SSL_CTX*` is reference counted. It will be destroyed after the last `SSL_free`.

Since you are using a common `SSL_CTX*`, you should tune each SSL session with the non-context API calls. For example, `SSL_set_cipher_list` rather than `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` or `SSL_use_certificate` rather than `SSL_CTX_use_certificate` (unless, of course, its common).

Comment: I found the solution. See my update at the bottom of my question. Also yes I am using common certs and ciphers for every session, so yes I am still using CTX APIs for now. I am now looking into session recovery concept with openssl. Openssl can get pretty complicated soon. I am interested to see how it is done using Openssl and are they any potential security problems if implemented incorrectly.